# React native ios remote js debugger unavailable

Tags: react-native

The code compiles fine and runs the app as expected and the debugger works fine on android.
RCTWebSocket is present in ios libraries and compiles and runs fine.
I've tried everything I could think of:

1. Reinstall xcode.
2. Yarn clean
3. Downgrade emulator version
4. Downgrade RN and Node version.
5. Kill a dragon and others.

[image: After clicking on Remote JS Debugger Unavailable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was not able to get rid of the bug but here's a workaround that might help someone:
1) Kill the packager and restart it and run the app.
2) Press `cmd + D` before the packager fully loaded and provided the js files, there is a time window when the debug option is available.